# How to keep fixed div on the left and relative div on the right as resizable container

Tags: css, html

I have two containers both are relative and both are set float right. My target is that, the left container to give height 100% of the screen and in a fixed position. But when I do it, all the other elements get broken. Suggestions kindly appreciated.

**http://jsfiddle.net/VpxeC/3/**

```
<div class="outleftcontainerunder">
</div>


<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="innermaincontainer">
        <div class="articlebutton"></div>
        <div class="discussionbutton"></div>
        <div class="editbutton"></div>
        <div class="searchbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    body
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .outleftcontainerunder
    {
        width: 175px;
        height: 250px;
        background: green;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    .maincontainer
    {
        width: calc(100% - 175px);
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the height of `.maincontainer` to `100%+50px`?

Comment: @Paddyd not important. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the float on the left container, and move the main container to the right it should work how I *think* you want it to.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VpxeC/2/

```
.outleftcontainerunder /*I want this div to be in position fixed and height as 100% of the screen. But when I do it, there is a chaos*/
{
  width: 175px;
  height: 250px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
 }

.maincontainer
{
  width: calc(100% - 175px);
  left: 175px;
  height: calc(100% + 50px);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VpxeC/1/)

```
.outleftcontainerunder
{
    width: 175px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
    left:0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Also modified this:

```
.maincontainer
{
    float: right;
}
```